# how to create a code 128 barcode with a function 3 character?

Tags: java, barcode, code128

I am using iText for java. I am trying to create a Code128 barcode with a FNC3 character at the beginning of the barcode. Can anyone help me with this? 
Here is my code:

```
try {
Barcode128 barcode = new Barcode128();
barcode.setCode((char)228 + "92");
Image img = barcode.createAwtImage(Color.black, Color.white);
lblBarcode.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

}
catch(Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes. I get "Illegal characters" error.
java.lang.RuntimeException: There are illegal characters for barcode 128 in 'Ä92'.
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode128.getRawText(Barcode128.java:379)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode128.createAwtImage(Barcode128.java:795)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a code that starts with FNC3 use `barcode.setCode(""+FNC3+<rest of barcode>)`. The `FNC3` constant is located in `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode`

Comment: vandale - when using your suggestion, I get the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: There are illegal characters for barcode 128 in 'Ä92'.
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode128.getRawText(Barcode128.java:379)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode128.createAwtImage(Barcode128.java:795)

Comment: @user3005743 are you sure that the `FNC3 92` is a valid barcode?

Comment: it should be. I can generate that barcode in .NET using a different barcode library. It is a programming barcode for Symbol/Motorola barcode scanners.

Comment: @user3005743 try `\u0060` `\u00C9` or `\u00F1` instead of `FNC3` and see if it works

Comment: Well, it doesn't error out. When I scan it I get a `92 in notepad which is not what is supposed to happen. The scanner should be reading it as a programming barcode.

Comment: It worked. If I added the Barcode128.START_B + "\u0060" + "92" it generates properly with no error.

Comment: @user3005743 good, Its from the value column on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#Bar_code_widthshttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#Bar_code_widths